# Android: AIRMap was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

So i'm trying to implement a map view in my react native app, using react-native-maps. When i'm installing it with npm it's all good, and linking it makes no errors. The problem is when i try to run it, then I get the

> Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "AIRMap" was not fount in the UIManager.

I've narrowed it down to being on the Android side, since that's the emulator i'm running. For some reason, the gradle files seems broken and I have no idea of what it can be. I've tried most guides i've found but none seems to handle the issue. I've tried to link it manually, remove the link and so on. I've also tried adding the direct link to GitHub which doesn't solve it either.

Some build info:

> React version: 0.60.0
>
> Gradle version: 5.4.1
>
> Emulator version: Pie API 28

settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'ProjectName'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle");     
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
```

build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+
implementation project(':react-native-maps')
```

MapView:

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'
 <MapView
          region={{
            latitude: 42.882004,
            longitude: 74.582748,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
          ></MapView>
```

Lastly, I have also created an API to Google maps in the android project.
The project is manageable to recreate by initiating a new react-native project and implementing react-native-maps

Comment: Starting from React Native 0.60.0 the use of AndroidX will be enforced. All your Android code and libraries will need to be updated to work with AndroidX as well. I checked and it seems `react-native-maps` isn't quite ready. See [this issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2839) and try the proposed workarounds, maybe that will help.

Answer (score 2):

## For Android

### `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="28"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      <!-- You will only need to add this meta-data tag, but make sure it's a child of application -->
      <meta-data
              android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
              android:value="AIzDDDBBLn-PhCtBM1AnC_h66yH8Lw2DDD14WW0"/>
    </application>
```

### `MainApplication.java`

```java
import java.util.List;
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;  // <-- Add this line

...


        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          packages.add(new MapsPackage()); // <-  ADD THIS LINE
          return packages;
        }
```

### `android/settings.gradle`

if you are not using `monorepo` technique

```rb
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../../../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
```

### `android/build.gradle`

```java
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        supportLibVersion = '28.0.0'
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0" // or find latest version
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "17.0.0" // or find latest version
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "2.2.3"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google() // keep google() at last
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../../../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../../../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        google() // keep google() at last
    }
}
```

### `android/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {

    ...


    implementation project(':react-native-maps') // at last
}
```

### Notes

1. I am using `../../../node_modules` because I am using Monorepo technique to maintain 2 apps in one git repo
2. `../node_modules` might work for you
3. keep `google()` at last of the code-block

---

## IOS

See this for solution in IOS https://stackoverflow.com/a/67945288/3437900