# RCTConvert+AirMap.h file not found Error on React Native on IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

[image]

i have this Error . RCTConvert+AirMap.h file not found Error on React Native on IOS

Comment: facing same error. @cute soft did you got the workaround?

Comment: Try the method specified [here](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/3597#issuecomment-1168582636)

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this with:

1. Adding **`$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/ios/AirMaps`** in the project target header
2. Moving the **`pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path` above use_native_modules** (it was previously below that) in the `Podfile`
3. Added:

```
  post_install do |installer|
      //...
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
        end
      end
      
    end
  end
```

4. after step 3 if still not working remove all the cache
   (`pod deintegrate`, `pod install`, `remove derived data`, `clean build`)

Comment: A little note: Adding a title must be done here.  XCODE => MyProject -> MyProject(Target) -> Build Settings -> Header Search Path

Answer (score 3):

Latest Update

### For config similar or latest

```
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.28.0",
```

Its pretty much easier to configure React Native Maps using GoogleMap and other map providers.

Auto-linking does not solve the problem so you will have to manually tell `xcode` where the native code is.
There are 2 ways to tell

1. Manually add files/folders to Xcode [using these instructions here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-integrate-maps-in-react-native-using-react-native-maps-5745490fe055/)
2. The Simplest. No need to goto `Xcode` for tweaking `header search path`

### 2. Simplest

```rb
# Podfile

pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => '../../../node_modules/react-native-maps/'
pod 'react-native-maps', :path => '../../../node_modules/react-native-maps/'

# These might not be necessary
# Please build without these. If could not build, add these as well
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
```

in `AppDelegate.m` file

```m
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h> // this line is alreaady there.  Add the line below
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

...

...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions // this line is alreaady there.  Add the line below
{
+  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaEEBBLn-PhCDDD1AnC_h66yH8LEEUkd14WW0"]; // add this line using the api key obtained from Google Console
```

Notes:

1. replace `AIzaEEBBLn-PhCDDD1AnC_h66yH8LEEUkd14WW0` with your own API Key from google console.
2. In my case I am using monorepo technique so `'../../../node_modules/react-native-maps/'`. In your case its `'../node_modules/react-native-maps/'`
3. **`+` and `-` sign should be used. They are language defined entities. No type error**

Comment: Why did you reveal your Google Maps API key? :-D

Answer (score 1):

Additional statements need to be added to `Podfile`:

```
# Podfile:
...
# Platform should be at least 13.0
platform :ios, '13.0'
...

# add the following 2 statements
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'

target 'casualjob' do
    # add the following 2 statements (if not present)
    rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
    pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
    ....

    post_install do |installer|
    ...
    # add the following section
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
        end
      end
    end
    ...
  end
```

Additional statements need to be added to `AppDelegate.mm`:

```m
// AppDelegate.mm
...
#import "AppDelegate.h"
...
// Add the following statement (if not present)
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  // add the following statement (if not present)
  // Replace YOUR_API_KEY below with your project's Google API Key
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR_API_KEY"];
...
}
...
```

For the configuration:

```
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.1",
"react-native-maps": "^1.3.2",
```

Answer (score 1):

That was an issue I faced on `react-native-maps` version `1.4.0`, and as per https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/4563#issuecomment-1513857960, upgrading to the newest version fixed the problem.

Comment: I installed version 1.6.0 and its still happening

Comment: @jose920405, my app is on `1.7.1`, maybe try this one.

Answer (score 0):

this is due to the static framework using. you need some changing in your podfile. here is the pod file for **react-native 0.70.6**

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false
production = ENV["PRODUCTION"] == "1"
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' ,"9.12.0"
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook','6.11.0.0'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'

target 'myApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  $static_framework = []
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  $RNGoogleMobileAdsAsStaticFramework = true
  $RNAdMobAsStaticFramework = true
  $FirebaseSDKVersion = '10.2.0'
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  pre_install do |installer|
  Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}

  installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    if pod.name.eql?('RNPermissions') || pod.name.start_with?('Permission-')
      def pod.build_type;
        # Uncomment the line corresponding to your CocoaPods version
        Pod::BuildType.static_library # >= 1.9
        # Pod::Target::BuildType.static_library # < 1.9
      end
    end
  end
end


  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => true,
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    # :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )
  $static_framework += [
    'react-native-maps',
    'react-native-google-maps',
    'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils',
    'GoogleMaps',
    'RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework',
    'RNGoogleMobileAdsAsStaticFramework',
    'RNAdMobAsStaticFramework'

  ]
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
  pod 'Permission-Contacts', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Contacts"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibraryAddOnly', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibraryAddOnly"  
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  target 'myAppTest' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # ****** THIS IS THE MAGIC ******
  pre_install do |installer|
    Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
        installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
            if $static_framework.include?(pod.name)
                def pod.build_type;
                Pod::BuildType.static_library # >= 1.9
            end
        end
    end
  end
  # ****** THIS IS THE MAGIC ENDED  ******
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    
    #############
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        ### Added for Maps
        if target.name == 'RCT-Folly'
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] = "$(inherited) ${PODS_ROOT}/fmt/include"
          end
        end

        #### Added For Maps Ended 
        if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
             # config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "i386 arm64"
          end
        end
      end
    ############
   # __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)  # comment for maps
   ## there two linesare added for maps
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Would you explain how this solves the issue?